# What is the name of this plant

Tags: identification, shrubs

Hope someone can identify this plant for me----Thank you[image]

Comment: Please give us more information. :)  Where was this photo taken?  What plant, specifically are you wanting information on.

Comment: Looks like Pampas Grass if they are talking about the one in the center.

Comment: If its the tall grass you want an ID for, please add an image taken closer to the stems and leaves

Comment: @user19765 This question is likely to be closed unless you provide more details. I didn't cast a close vote because I think you might appreciate us waiting a day or two, so please upload a pic that shows the leaves if you want to find out what's its name. If you forgot your credentials, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

[karl forester reed grass](https://www.brokenarrownursery.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/470x470/37d30b3d94e9a06722db93e171ffc8c1/c/a/calamagrostis_x_acutiflora_karl_foerster_habit_-_scott_arboretum_-_july_26_2012.jpg)  Without being able to look at those seed heads this might also be a good contender.  Could you please send close ups of the seed 
heads?

[Pampas grass pictures](http://Pampas%20Grass) It could still be Pampas Grass as well.  Need a close up of the seed head as well as the leave...or where those leaves join the stem.

My experience with Pampas grass includes trying to clean out, clean up, thin or control and lots of humongous rats.  Great rat housing!